# How to get discount rate when PV, FV and Rate is known

Tags: r

I would like to find the rate when pv, fv, and the number of periods are given. Suppose, FV = 133.1, PV = 100, n = 2. I need to get r = 10. Any help?

```r
fv = \(pv, n, r) pv*(1 + r/100)^n 
fv(100, 3, 10)
#> [1] 133.1
```

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're looking for?  Do you need the equation for r in terms of `fv`, `pv` and `n`?  If so, `r =((fv/pv)^(1/n)-1) * 100`.

Comment: @DaveArmstrong This works. Actually, I thought of using some sort of optimizing function to find this.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is an algebra question, not a programming question.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution.
Use `uniroot` to find the root of the non-linear function giving the discount rate:

`pv == fv/(1 + r)^n`
`pv*(1 + r)^n == fv`
`pv*(1 + r)^n - fv == 0`

It's this last one that needs to be solved.

**Note: I have left the percentage factor 100 out of the code, change it at will.**

```r
DR <- function(pv, fv, n) {
  dr <- function(x, pv, fv, n) {
      pv*(1 + x)^n - fv
  }
  uniroot(dr, pv = pv, fv = fv, n = n, 
          interval = c(0, 100), tol = .Machine$double.eps^0.5)
}
FV <- function(pv, r, n) {
  pv * (1 + r)^n
}

r <- DR(100, 133.1, 3)
r$root
#> [1] 0.1

FV(100, r = 0.10, n = 3)
#> [1] 133.1
FV(100, r = r$root, n = 3)
#> [1] 133.1
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

---

The solution above envolving `uniroot` is too complicated, there's an analytic one given in [DaveArmstrong's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72929730/how-to-get-discount-rate-when-pv-fv-and-rate-is-known/72930059#comment128812135_72929730).

```r
DR <- function(pv, fv, n) {
  (fv/pv)^(1/n) - 1
}

fv <- 133.1
pv <- 100
n <- 3

r <- DR(pv, fv, n)
r
#> [1] 0.1

FV(pv, r, n)
#> [1] 133.1
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>